# Open PDF in Microsoft Edge without showing a URL bar

Tags: windows, pdf-reader

When I open a PDF I downloaded in Firefox, it opens like this:

[image: Image. Screenshot of an open PDF. No file location is shown. An address bar is entirely absent]

However, when I open a PDF from the file explorer, it opens like this:

[image: Image. Screenshot of an open PDF. The path to the open file's location is shown in an address bar in the user interface]

With an annoying URL bar taking up a portion of my screen. How do I make PDFs opened through the file explorer open as PDFs opened through the downloads in Firefox?

Comment: Press `[F11]` ?

Comment: Set the default file association to Firefox instead of Edge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same problem
i fixed it by opening command prompt in administrator mode then typing the command

```
ftype MSEdgePDF="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" "--app=%1"
```

what it does is it edits the microsoft edge file association for opening pdfs to launch it in app mode

it should return the value

```
MSEdgePDF="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" "--app=%1"
```

make sure you set msedge as your default pdf viewer

in general you can open pdfs in that mode by launching the mesedge exe  through cmd with the `--app=<pdf file>` option

hope it works for you as well!

(i figured this out by finding the command used by firefox when opening pdfs through edge using procmon, then figuring out how to change the default file association with a custom command)

Answer (score 0):

you can use F11 key to hide URL of PDF file on your Firefox web browser (it is worked for Microsoft edge and Google Chrome  )[image]

Comment: this is different since it also hides the minimize, and close button and only allows for full screen mode.